# 404 error with unique twist

Tags: php, .htaccess, wampserver

I recently reinstalled `wampserver3 w/php 5.6.16 & php 7`. `Composer` is also installed globally with `laravel` framework. The reason for my reinstall is because my project folder on localhost would throw 404 errors when accessed. I have edited `$suppresslocalhost` to `false` to no avail. My php error log shows:  > PHP Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT.

I run on a `windows 7 x64`.

I can access localhost, phpmyadmin, phpinfo.

I may have something different in this 404 error. As stated I have revised `$suppresslocalhost` to `false` and I also renamed my `.htaccess` file, which by the way will not allow me to rename it `.htaccess` but that's another topic for different time, to a file name in my `WAMP` root.

thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName localhost 
    DocumentRoot e:/wamp64/www/ 
    <Directory "e:/wamp64/www/"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
        AllowOverride All 
        Require local 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName base4 
    DocumentRoot e:/wamp64/www/base4/ 
    <Directory "e:/wamp64/www/base4/"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
        AllowOverride All 
        Require local 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName localhost 
    DocumentRoot e:/wamp64/www 
    <Directory "e:/wamp64/www/"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
        AllowOverride All 
        Require local 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName test.dev 
    DocumentRoot e:/wamp64/www/test.dev 
    <Directory "e:/wamp64/www/test.dev/"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
        AllowOverride All 
        Require local 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If it's Windows preventing you from renaming a file to `.htaccess` you can do it through a `cmd` prompt, call the file htaccess.txt then navigate to the folder through the cmd and type `REN htaccess.txt .htaccess` ... bizarrely it's only the Windows GUI that sulks about it "not having a filename" the underlying OS is fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to create a Virtual Host for each of your projects.

It sounds like you have WAMPServer3 installed. In that version you can create Virtual Hosts at the click of a button. It does everything for you!

First create the directory you want to put this site into if you have not already done so.

The folder can be under `\wamp\www\project1\www` if you like or in any other folder, for example `C:\websrc\project1\www`.

Look at the WAMPServer home page and click on the `Add a Virtual Host` link under the `TOOLS` column and then follow the SIMPLE INSTRUCTIONS

WAMPServer will automatically restart Apache so the new Virtual Host is seen by Apache.

Once its complete do :-

```
rightclick wampmanager -> tools -> Restart DNS
```

You might also see some other useful NEW features on the wampmanager right click menu!

Comment: I followed all steps provided however my project/alias/virtual folders are still giving 404 errors. My only changes were an expansion to wamp menu and virtual host was added to my localhost homepage.

Comment: Add your httpd-vhosts.conf file to your question so I can see whats in there please

Comment: The only way to access my files is to type file path into address bar. With this method access to index is allowed.

Comment: Assuming you created a Virtual Host called `test.dev` once you have the VH configured you can access the site using `test.dev`, forget the localhost bit completely

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot e:/wamp64/www/
 <Directory  "e:/wamp64/www/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require local
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName base4
 DocumentRoot e:/wamp64/www/base4/
 <Directory  "e:/wamp64/www/base4/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require local
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Thats looks fine. Are you sure you dont have a `.htaccess` file in `e:/wamp64/www/base4/` that could be causing issues?

Comment: What did you change, can you not see I added your previous unreadable comment to your question

Comment: I have been researching and trying to find my own answer however nothing seem to work. I check my .htaccess file for errors and it seems to be ok. my .htaccess file look like this:  RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] any tips would help.

Comment: I was studying my issue online and come across your wampserver instruction so I am "stupid" because I did not back my working version of wamp. I have gone back to wamp 2.5 which seems clunky but it works better. There are still some glitches that needs to be worked out however I can display my code through firefox. My project folder is still not working but I am working on it. I know this is not a question but I just wanted to inform you of my issue and the only way I knew how was through so.com.